# How to use the DownloadCache plugin?

Tags: mvvmcross

I am using MvvmCross in my Android project. I have a `MvxRecyclerView` that contains an image in each item (downloaded from a url), and there are hundreds of items, so I want to use the `DownloadCache` plugin to help me manage the images/memory so my app doesn't crash with a OutOfMemory exception.

Ideally, when the image/memory limit has been reached, the first image that was downloaded (and is the farthest non-visible item in the `MvxRecyclerView`) should be freed to make room for the next visible item with its image.

I found the source for it here:
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/MvvmCross-Plugins/DownloadCache

How can I use this plugin to achieve this?

**EDIT**

After trying a few things, I'm stuck over this error that I get when I call `Mvx.Resolve<IMvxImageCache<byte[]>>().RequestImage(myImageUrl)`

> Failed to resolve type
>   MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.IMvxLocalFileImageLoader

I'm registering the type like this so I don't know why it can't resolve it:

```
Mvx.ConstructAndRegisterSingleton<IMvxLocalFileImageLoader<Bitmap>, MvxAndroidLocalFileImageLoader>();
```

I'm registering the `IMvxImageCache` like this:

```
Mvx.RegisterSingleton(typeof(IMvxImageCache<byte[]>), () =>
{
  return new MvxImageCache<byte[]>(Mvx.Resolve<IMvxFileDownloadCache>(), 2, 5000000, true);
});
```

I feel like I'm doing something wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is available [here](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/downloadcache?scroll=1000). The documentation seems to suggest:

1. Use `MvxImageView` instead of `ImageView`.
2. Use `MvxDownloadCacheConfiguration` in `Setup.GetPluginConfiguration` override to customize the cache options as needed.

Comment: And how does the binding work? Does `MvxImageView` have a property that I can bind the url of the image, and everything else is done by the library?

Comment: You could use the `ImageUrl` binding. Everything else should be taken care of by the library.

Comment: I set `MvxDownloadCacheConfiguration.Default.MaxFiles = 1;` but I was able to download 2 images when binding `ImageUrl` to 2 different images on the internet. So I don't think it's that simple..

Comment: I think that if you set `MaxFiles=1` or something unreasonable, it will just ignore it.